# Gitlab private repository via composer

Tags: composer-php, repository, gitlab

Today I have created private repository in gitlab and want to install it via composer in my laravel project, but  when I run `composer update` I am getting the following error

> Your configuration does not allow connections to ...........

Here is a  part of my **composer.json**

```
"repositories": [{
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "abc/def",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "type": "package",
            "source": {
                "url": "http://gitlab.abc.pro/abc/def",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
        }
    } ],
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "abc/def" : "dev-master",  
    },
```

Comment: i could bet it is the http instead of https. try to change it in the repositories section or allow it in your global composer config `composer config -g secure-http false`

Comment: Thanks for reply. @NormanM I have solved already, the problem comes from public and private key which I need to have in my ssh .

Comment: @YurGasparyan if you solved the issue, then answer your post how you solved step by step, so that it will help others in future if any encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
"repositories": [
    {
     "type": "vcs",
      "url": "ssh://git@gitlab.yourdomain.com/repo/private.git"
    }
]
```

and this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "repo/private": "dev-master",
 }
```

Comment: It's great. Thanks for sharing. On Composer manual all ask to set the ssh key and when we only put git@github.com:foo/secret.git without ssh it will always fallback to http method. It quite bothersome

Comment: why we use vcs but not git ?

Answer (score 0):

For easy using gitlab repository I have used [packagist](https://packagist.org) service, so you need to go to settings of your gitlab repository and set oAuth token which have been taken from packagist. For using private repositories you need to get public and private keys and set it in gitlab repo.