# Composer and local dependencies

Tags: composer-php

I am wanting to use Composer to manage my own private libraries used at work, and use them on intranet projects at work.

Publishing code to packagist or github is *NOT* an option per company rules; all code is to remain within our own walls so to speak.

I have figured out how to include libraries into my intranet web app on an individual basis:

**composer.json for web app**

```
{
    "name": "myapp/appname",
    "description": "app that uses some of my libraries",
    "require": {
      "tmorton/dataaccessobjects": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
      {
        "type":"vcs",
        "url":"//path/to/library"
      }

    ]
}
```

My problem is that this collection of data access objects has a dependency on my crud library.

So it seems that I should be able to `require` the crud library in the composer.json in the dataaccessobjects library:

**composer.json for data access objects**

```
{
    "name": "tmorton/dataaccessobjects",
    "description": "Data Access Objects for a set of specific tables",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "path",
        "url":"//path/to/crud/library"
      }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
      "tmorton/crud": "^2.0.0"
    }
}
```

My DAO objects are cloned into app/vendor, but Crud is not brought in.

All the documentation I've seen talks about publishing to third party locations, but nothing about from local sources.

I can, of course do this; but it defeats the whole idea of managing dependencies (I shouldn't have to know which version of crud is required at this point)

**composer.json for web app**

```
{
    "name": "myapp/appname",
    "description": "app that uses some of my libraries",
    "require": {
      "tmorton/dataaccessobjects": "^1.0.0",
      "tmorton/crud": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
      {
        "type":"vcs",
        "url":"//path/to/dao/library"
      },
      {
        "type": "path",
        "url":"//path/to/crud/library"
      }

    ]
}
```

I'm hoping somebody can fill in some concepts that I appear to be missing.

---

The answer to a [suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223251/load-composer-dependencies-of-private-git-repository) seems to indicate that `type: "package"` won't work.  I'm not using `type: "package"`.

> package type is for non-composer dependencies. If you use this type, Composer will not even look for composer.json file inside of defined package source, you need to include all required information about package inside of the package declaration in your project composer.json

What I'm gathering is that no matter what you do, composer-- by itself-- isn't going to bother looking up dependencies of included items.  Somehow it works when grabbing 3rd party stuff, but there's obviously something else doing the work.  My guess is it's the hosting itself?

Comment: The best way is using private composer repository in intranet - satis for example. https://github.com/composer/satis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load composer dependencies of private git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223251/load-composer-dependencies-of-private-git-repository)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919675/gitlab-private-repository-via-composer

Comment: Are you using git? Which you should of course ;)

Comment: I will definitely look into satis.  The other comments really do not shed any light on what I'm missing other than to suggest that composer is not capable of what I want it to do; a conclusion I'm trying to overcome.

Comment: @ivoba Yes, I'm using git.  And composer's insistence on cloning instead of copying  completely broke  my push-to-production flow because anything composer brought into /vendor is, apparently by design, supposed to be gitignored.  Once I overcame my irritation at bringing in code that I couldn't push, I changed my post-receive hook in production to run composer on the production side.   Which means I've created a dependency on composer itself in production.  smh...

Comment: ...and speaking of dependencies, when I installed satis, it prompted me for a GitHub Oauth token, so I mistakenly generated a new one and put it in...  WHICH BROKE COMPOSER.  https://nono.ma/github-oauth-token-for-github-com-contains-invalid-characters-on-composer-install  So if I hadn't figured out why Composer mysteriously broke, I'd no longer be able to push any upgrades to development.  IMHO, this is not what I consider progress; it's making more opportunities to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that running a intranet satis comes with some overhead of administrating which is why i also stopped using it.

Here is what i would recommend in your situation:

1. Use git for internal packages:
   You have a private git repo somewhere and require this with the [repository directive of composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md)

   "require": {
   "my/package": "dev-main"
   ...
   },
   "repositories": [
   {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "git@bitbucket.org:my/package.git"
   }
   ]

Of course don't commit the vendor dir but do commit composer.lock.

**Update:**
Note that you will need to add repositories of private subpackages also in the repositories block of the project's composer.json.
So when `my/package` requires another private package `my/package2`, add this`my/package2` as well to `repositories` block of your projects composer.json.

2. Use builds for deployment
   With tools like [deployer](https://deployer.org/) you can easily run composer on production and symlink to the succesfull build/release after all is run.
   Here you also have a dependency on composer on your production machine, but deployer usually installs the phar itself, outside the web root.
   If this is not suitable you can also do a local build with deployer and sync to your production system via rsync:
   https://deployer.org/docs/advanced/deploy-strategies.html#build-server
   Here you locally checkout from git in a build dir, run there composer locally and push to production via rsync.

Comment: Regarding deployment- after I accepted the idea of having to run composer on production, it dawned on me that my post-receive hook could not only set the git tree, but also run composer. (duh!) So with one added line, deployment works like a champ :) That leaves the issue of dependencies:

Comment: I’m using git repos for each of my packages. I tried running composer on them to pull in dependencies, but of course they went into the package’s `vendor` directory which would have been a mess when I used them in a project. But are you saying that if the lock file is built in each package (with `vendor` ignored), the project will pull those dependencies?

Comment: No, commit the lock file in the project that uses the packages. Dont commit the lock file in the packages.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having a bit of a disconnect with what you're trying to get across to me.  I'm able to bring in packages into my project via  repositories; the problem is if a package has a dependency, it is not included.  Now... I *could* get the composer lock from each of the packages to build a list of requirements and manually paste them all into the project's composer lock... but it feels like that would be asking for trouble.  Is this what you're suggesting?

Comment: If you define the dependencies of your package in your packages "require" block of your package's composer.json, these dependencies will be pulled into your main project.

Comment: That seems like the way it should work, but it's not doing that for me.  Project requires Package A.  Package A requires Package B.  Project gets Package A but not Package B.  I tried running composer install on Package A, and committed composer.json and composer.lock but ignored /vendor.  Tagged Package A as a new version.  Project still doesn't load Package B.  Now of course I could copy the require key of Package A (ie, require Package B) and append that to the project's require key of composer.json-- but then what good is a "dependency manager" if ***I*** am managing the dependencies?

Comment: Am I still missing what you're saying?

Comment: Well... something changed.  Now it's pulling in the package, but not the right version.  At least that's progress :)

Comment: Eureka!  Wrong version was because project's lock file had wrong version.  Wiped out the lock file and installed from scratch and it worked.  I think the problem was that I didn't include all repositories in the project's composer.json file.  Composer apparently won't look up the repository from the package.  So in the project file, require Package A, and provide the repository location for Package A **and** Package B.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you'd be so kind as to make reference to the project only needing to require the package that names its dependencies, but the project must name all repositories used by dependencies.  Thanks for giving me the hope that it really was possible!

Comment: Glad that it worked out for you. I updated the answer with your findings.